# How to make ExtJS chart background transparent?

Tags: flash, extjs

It's white now and I need it to be transparent. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Outdated question, not relevant anymore.

Comment: Unsure why this us defined as not about programming

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to add `<param name="wmode" value="transparent">`  to your object tag in HTML. [reed this article](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/142/tn_14201.html) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Given the fact that extjs stacks many layers of canvases (is this the right plural?) I've achieved chart transparency (on extjs 5) by doing this:

```
bodyStyle: 'background:transparent !important;'
```

for both your CHART and it's CONTAINER (in my case a panel).
In addition to this, set

```
background: {
            style: {
                opacity: 0.0
            }
        }
```

for your chart. The interesting is that if now you keep the bodyStyle configuration and set the opacity to 1.0 in the style, your chart will still be transparent. Perhaps extjs doesn't check for opacity changes if background in unset.

Answer (score 0):

I used FireBug to replace the white background of Ext JS (3.3) grids with an image of my choosing.  I removed/replaced background, borders, and CSS for active rows for grid DIVs and TABLE.  I started with this:

```
.x-grid3 { background: none; }
```